# Add a link to the header links only if a customer is signed in

Tags: magento2, layout, cache, session

When a customer is logged in, I'd like to add a custom link to Magento's header links, like below:
[image]

So far, I've been able to add the link by adding the below to the default.xml file from my theme, but it adds it even when the customer is logged out, I need it to only be added there when the customer is logged in:

```
<referenceBlock name="header.links">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link" name="custom-link" before="-">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Custom Link</argument>
            <argument name="path" xsi:type="string" translate="true">custom</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceBlock>
```

Answer (score 2):

In the end I followed the same approach as Magento does by adding the *module-customer/view/frontend/templates/account/customer.phtml* template.

I added a new block to the header links section in my themes default.xml

```
<referenceBlock name="header.links">
    <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Customer" name="custom.link" template="Magento_Theme::custom-link.phtml" before="-"/>
</referenceBlock>
```

Then I created a *custom-link.phtml* file in my theme, and checked if the user was logged in with **$block->customerLoggedIn()**

```
<?php
/** @var Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Customer $block */
?>
<?php if($block->customerLoggedIn()): ?>
    <li><a href="<?= $this->getBaseUrl().'custom-link'?>"><?= __('Custom Link')?></a></li>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending of where do you want to place it, if on header panel or at the dropdown just change in code above **header.links** to **top.links**:

*magento_root/app/code/SomeVendorName/HeaderLoggedInLink/view/frontend/layout/default.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="header.links">
            <block name="custom-block-name" template="SomeVendorName_HeaderLoggedInLink::newlink.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="view_model"
                          xsi:type="object">SomeVendorName\HeaderLoggedInLink\Block\AnyBlockName</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

***All other module files:***

*magento_root/app/code/SomeVendorName/HeaderLoggedInLink/etc/module.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="SomeVendorName_HeaderLoggedInLink" setup_version="0.1.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Customer"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

*magento_root/app/code/SomeVendorName/HeaderLoggedInLink/registration.php*:

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'SomeVendorName_HeaderLoggedInLink',
    __DIR__
);
```

*magento_root/app/code/SomeVendorName/HeaderLoggedInLink/view/frontend/templates/newlink.phtml*:

```
<?php
/** @var \SomeVendorName\HeaderLoggedInLink\Block\AnyBlockName $viewModel */
/** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template $block */

$viewModel = $block->getData('view_model')
?>

<?php if ($viewModel->getIsLOggedIn()): ?>
    <li class="customer-welcome">
        <a href="<?php echo $block->escapeUrl($block->getUrl('your_custom_frontname/your_custom_controller/you_custom_name')) ?>">
            <?php echo __('Your custom label for link') ?>
        </a>
    </li>
<?php endif; ?>
```

*magento_root/app/code/SomeVendorName/HeaderLoggedInLink/Block/AnyBlockName.php*:

```
<?php

namespace SomeVendorName\HeaderLoggedInLink\Block;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Block\ArgumentInterface;

class AnyBlockName implements ArgumentInterface
{
    /**
     * @var Session
    */
    private $customerSession;

    /**
     * AnyBlockName constructor.
     * @param Session $customerSession
     */
    public function __construct(Session $customerSession)
    {
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    }

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function getIsLOggedIn()
    {
        return $this->customerSession->isLoggedIn();
    }
}
```

If you'll choose top,links it will look like that:

[image: If you'll choose top,links it will look like that]

Comment: How to add Wish list link to after Create an account @Stepan Furman

Comment: Did you read my answer? You can add any link with any text in this way.